# Does anyone know a Chrome extension for search/replace using regular expressions?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, regex, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I want a Chrome extension that can do text replacements using regular expressions. Does anyone know one?

Answer (score 4):

Try these extensions:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pgnkpcgniljiolidjmodgfljeomjjiha
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/haocppnjhmfiemhgfdgockbipphbfibe

The first one allows you to search a page using regular expressions; the second allows you to see what would happen if you applied a regex to a block of text.  *I am not affiliated with the developer or publisher of these extensions.*

Comment: There's one more extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-replace/ojoeejfegihohnkjlfoonbnailkohkce I am its developer and still maintain it.